# Excel Turn Chunks of Text Into Columns

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I need to find a programmatic way to do the following. Basically, I have a text file with the followoing:

[image]

Of course, there is real data in there and there are several thousand different "chunks" like this. First, we would like to collapse Job Title 1 and Job Title 2 into a single line. Then, we need to import this into excel in a row format. Such as:

[image]

Comment: Will you be performing this conversion once, or this something you foresee doing multiple times? The reason I ask is that I could come up with a relatively easy solution that requires a small amount of manual setup, or I could come up with a difficult solution that could be run with the push of a button.

Comment: I will be doing this only one time, but after reviewing the data it appears that things aren't quite as simple as they seemed. It turns out some people have even up to 3 Job Title lines, and some don't have either an email or phone number. I doubt this would be possible to do in a timely manner.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is often the case with these types of files. You still might be able to attempt to automate a solution then go through and manually fix problems later. It all depends on how messy vs. uniform the original file is.

Answer (score 0):

I've tackled a similar problem at my job, and the data can actually be manipulated purely in Excel. Your first step is to just get it into Excel, open it in Notepad - copy, then paste into Excel - or optionally try to open it. The trick is to use the "blank row" as a trigger for a set or formulas that you just fill down. When it's done you copy all the results over to a new worksheet, and sort so all the blank rows get thrown away. You'll have to hack away at your data and merge the various results next - but that wont be too hard because you should get 3 different kinds of rows (those with 1 job, 2, 3) ..  just fix them with a unique formula each. Hopefully this gives you an idea of how to get started:

[image]

Comment: This makes sense, but let's say I have one person with a name, email, and a title that has a hard return in it but actually should be a single line, followed by another line with a title, and then the company name. Then the next person has only a company name.

Comment: wow well to be honest the data is a real mess then, I mean I can write any of these things in several programming languages outside of Excel - and even with that ability, there's no logical way to code for that kind of inconsistent data unless you have "markers" at these spots (common titles, etc) - blank rows were your best shot. However, all is not lost - I typically assign a person to clean up the data by hand before feeding it into the spreadsheet, a human being basically has to ensure some level of consistency first. Hope that helps.